# How to add commons-math library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-commons-math

I am trying to import common-math library to my Android Studio project. I placed the file  commons-math3-3.6.1.jar file in libs folder and in the gradle file I have this line:

```
compile 'commons-math3-3.6.1.jar'
```

But I get this error: `

> Error:(32, 0) Supplied String module notation
>   'commons-math3-3.6.1.jar' is invalid. Example notations:
>   'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2',
>   'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do?

Answer (score 9):

Is there a reason you need to use the jar file? You can get the file directly from Maven repository using something like this:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
```

Available on both JCenter and MavenCentral.

Answer (score 8):

in Android view open Gradle Scripts - build.gradle and add this to dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
```

You can also check their websites if newer version isn't available [list of latest versions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi)